# I need to display data from a dictionary of objects each with their own dictionary on a DataGrid using WPF with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid, caliburn.micro

So I have a `Dictionary<string, Language>` which is a collection of languages each containing a `BindableCollection<Translation>` keyed by the language name. A `Translation` is just a data model containing a key and a value. It's basically a dictionary, but I needed to bind the keys and values to text box's. All the languages have the same list of keys. I would like to be able to bind the ItemsSource to my `Dictionary<string, Language>` and have it output something like the following.

```
Key       | English    | Spanish          | ...
______________________________________________
username  | Username   |Nombre de usuario | ...
```

The only way I have found to be able to do this is to put all my data into a DataTable, but I need to be able to edit and add and remove columns and rows. My code is becoming a mess trying to wire up custom event handling to keep my data and my DataGrid in sync and I need to figure out a better more manageable solution. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Use a `DataTemplate` for your translation column

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like something you can handle with a few line of code.
Anyhow I would:

1. Create a Model with your `Dictionary<string, Language>`
2. Create a ViewModel with a `List<TranslationsRow>`

TranslationsRow would look like this:

```
class TranslationsRow
{
  public string Key;
  public string English;
  public string Spanish;
  public string German:
  // and so on...
}
```

3. Data bind you DataGrid to `List<TranslationsRow>`

You have to code by yourself the mappings between the Model (`Dictionary<string, Language>`) and the ViewModel (`List<TranslationsRow>`).
(In SQL this would be a PIVOT / UNPIVOT operation).

I think this is a perfect example of a ViewModel "converting" the Model data on behalf of the View.

Comment: This would work but I need to be able to add and remove languages at runtime.

Comment: I would use a fixed set of languages anyhow. TranslationRow could have Lang1, Lang2, Lang3 and so on. If you go up to Lang10 basically you are saying "the user can edit up to 10 languages at a time". Which ones are defined by the mapping logic and could be changed at runtime (ie ask the user before entering the editing form)

Comment: But then how do I make it so I only have columns generate for the languages that exist? Also I need the column headers to display the name of the language.

Comment: Start with a set of static columns. To change header       `MyDataGrid.Columns[1].Header = "German";` To hide unused columns `MyDataGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you have a dictionary which you want to bind to a TextBox while using the ShellViewModel of Caliburn Micro.

What I had to do in order to get the binding was set them all up in the code behind of the ShellView.  So I have a text box on the Window name=tb1.  In the constructor I coded:

```
InitializeComponent(); 
tb1.DataContext = ViewModels.ShellViewModel.myDictionary;
```

Then in the tb1 XAML I set the binding:

```
Text={Binding [myKey].myProperty, Mode=TwoWay}
```

I had to do this for each one.  Name it\Code behind\Bind it for each textbox.